# Selenium node failing to run IE or Chrome web drivers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

Here's simple batch file I wrote to start the node for selenium grid

```
 set webdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium-server\IEDriverServer.exe
echo %webdriver.ie.driver%
set webdriver.chrome.driver=C:\selenium-server\chromedriver.exe
echo %webdriver.chrome.driver%
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub
```

Yes both drivers exist in that directory and I've even added that directory to my System's Path variable. When I try to create a remote web driver like thus:

`Platform platform = Platform.WINDOWS;
            desiredCapabilities =new DesiredCapabilities("internet explorer", "9.0", platform);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(gridUrl), desiredCapabilities);`

I'm still getting an exception stating:

```
Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see htt
/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
```

I'm using the latest IEDriver and chromedriver and selenium server 2.32.0 (which I believe is the latest one too).

Running on windows 7.  I've tried both the 32 and 64 bit drivers for IE.  Get the same problem with the chrome driver.

Comment: This is always tricky. You need to install the correct browser version for the selenium to work perfectly. Check which browser version does that selenium server version support . cheers

Answer (score 4):

Adding this option at the end of the command to start my node got everything working.  Is this just poorly documented? did I miss something obvious?  or is there still something weird going on?

-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium-server\IEDriverServer.exe

Comment: You can also get this done by setting the PATH environment variable to the directory where drivers are present

Comment: You tried to use an environment variable (the "set" statements in your batch file). Environment variables and Java system properties are **not** interchangeable. The -D syntax is the proper way to set a Java system property from the command line.